# DetailSerializer to have listserializer property

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to add json data from the listserializer to the DetailSerializer class. The serializer looks something like this:
**serializer.py**

```
class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Fastest_laps
        fields = '__all__'

class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    listserializer = ListSerializer( read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = 
        ('place_of_birth','driver','listserializer','picture')
```

But i dont really see the data once i view it, i only see the detailserializer data( Driver model)

```
class Fastest_laps(models.Model):
    driver_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
    grand_prix = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    car_model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    time_taken = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=8)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.driver_name

class Driver(models.Model):

    place_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Fastest_laps, 
    db_column='driver_name')
    picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.driver)
```

**api.py**

```
class FastLapsSet(ModelViewSet):
queryset = Fastest_laps.objects.all()
serializer_class = ListSerializer

class DriverSet(ModelViewSet):
queryset = Driver.objects.all()
serializer_class = DetailSerializer
```

[image: api view]

Comment: show your api code

Comment: change the name of ListSerializer as it is rest frameworks builtin class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should rename your property as model name field:

```
class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    driver = ListSerializer(read_only=True)
    # ^^^
    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = 
        ('place_of_birth','driver','driver','picture')
```

or add the [source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) attribute:

```
class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    listserializer = ListSerializer(source='driver', read_only=True)
                                           #^^^^
    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = 
        ('place_of_birth','driver','listserializer','picture')
```

Comment: on doing this is an getting an error: TypeError at /driver/
'Fastest_laps' object is not iterable